# The $sort key specification must be an object

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to sort documents in my collection by a field that is a date object:

```
MyModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$skip": ( page.current-1 ) * 15 },
        { "$limit": 15 },
        { "$sort": "$personal.dateObject" }
    ], function..................... etc
```

And i am receiving this error:

```
{ [MongoError: exception:  the $sort key specification must be an object]
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception:  the $sort key specification must be an object',
  code: 15973,
  ok: 0 }
```

I don't know why, cause the personal.dateObject, is a object:

Example:

```
   "personal": {
        "dateObject": {
            "$date": "2015-11-20T02:00:00.000Z"
        },
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use Mongoose-style sort strings with `$sort`, you need to use an object:

```
MyModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$skip": ( page.current-1 ) * 15 },
        { "$limit": 15 },
        { "$sort": {"personal.dateObject": 1} }
    ],
```